# excerpt block from 2 text files and pipe to another utility

Tags: bash, sed, mailx

I'm trying to excerpt a bit of content from 2 text files and to send it as the body of an e-mail using the mailx program. I am trying to do this as a bash script, since I do have at least a limited amount of experience with creating simple bash scripts and so have a rudimentary knowledge in this area. That said, I am not opposed to entertaining other scripting options such as perl/python/whatever.

I've gotten partway to where I'd like to be using sed: `sed -e '1,/excerpt delimiter 1/d' -e '/excerpt delimiter 2/,$d' file1.txt && sed -e '1,/excerpt delimiter one/d' -e '/excerpt delimiter two/,$d' file2.txt` outputs to stdout the content I'm aiming to get into the e-mail body. But piping said content to mailx is not working, for reasons that are not entirely clear to me. That is to say that `sed -e '1,/excerpt delimiter 1/d' -e '/excerpt delimiter 2/,$d' file1.txt && sed -e '1,/excerpt delimiter one/d' -e '/excerpt delimiter two/,$d' file2.txt | mail -s excerpts me@mymail.me` does not send the output of both sed commands in the body of the e-mail: it only sends the output of the final sed command. I'm trying to understand why this is and to remedy matters by getting the output of both sed commands into the e-mail body.

Further background. The two text files contain many lines of text and are actually web page dumps I'm getting using lynx browser. I need just a block of a few lines from each of those files, so I'm using sed to delimit the blocks I need and to allow me to excise out those few lines from each file. My task might be easier and/or simpler if I were trying to excise from just one file rather than from two. But since the web pages with the content I'm after require entry of login credentials, and because I am trying to automate this process, I am using lynx's cmd_script option to first log in, then save (print-to-file, actually) the pages I need. lynx does not offer any way, so far as I can tell, to concatenate files, so I seem stuck with working with two separate files.

There must certainly be alternate ways of accomplishing my aim and I am not constrained, either by preference or by necessity, to use any particular utility. The only real constraint is, since I'm trying to automate this, that it be done as a script I can invoke as a cron job. I am using Linux and have at my disposal all the standard text manipulating tools. As may be clear, my scripting knowledge/abilities are quite limited, so I've been trying to accomplish what I'm aiming at using a one-liner. mailx is properly configured and working on this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe only applies to the first command in the `&&` list. You need combine the two into a *single* compound command whose output is piped to `mailx`.

```
{ sed -e '1,/excerpt delimiter 1/d' \ 
      -e '/excerpt delimiter 2/,$d' file1.txt &&
  sed -e '1,/excerpt delimiter one/d' \
      -e '/excerpt delimiter two/,$d' file2.txt ; } |
 mail -s excerpts me@mymail.me
```

Comment: This is probably something they teach in bash scripting 101 but something that those of us who have no formal training but are just fiddling around trying to accomplish limited tasks will not know. The curly braces resolved the issue for me--thanks chepner